# Nexus 4 (Android 4.3) doesn't have "Advanced Settings"

Tags: settings, nexus-4, 4.3-jelly-bean

The majority of tweaks I see people mentioning online are in the "Advanced" settings panel, which my Nexus 4 lacks. Also missing are "Lock Screen" settings. Why are they missing from my Settings app, and how can I get them back? (preferably without having to mess around with custom ROMs/Cyanogen mod)

Comment: What kinds of tweaks specifically are you looking for? It sounds like they simply aren't available on vanilla Android. That's part of the draw of custom ROMs - they provide extra options and features that standard Android does not. I don't think you'll be able to easily "add" them to your Settings, and even if you did they would likely not work correctly since the underlying implementation (in the frameworks and what not) would be absent.

Comment: For example, the lock screen interface can have 5 points to which the lock can be moved, with each one being assignable to an application to launch (or to the right to unlock). I've seen this on many of my friends devices (not running CM) under settings>lock screen which I don't have on my N4

Comment: That's not a standard feature of Android. It's either added by the manufacturer's UI components or they're using a lock screen replacement app.

Comment: Strange, it seemed REALLY well integrated.

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX the source code for Android is available, so it's easy for custom ROMs such as Cyanogen mod to add features in a "well integrated" way. For instance the Cyanogen way of implementing t9-style selections from the contacts felt better integrated than the actual feature as implemented in Android 4.3!